# When can "dazu" be split?

Tags: preposition

I encountered this conversation:

> ~ Willst du Bier trinken?
>
> = Und wie ich **da** Lust **zu** habe!

Why are "da" und "zu" separated? Shouldn't be like this?

> Und wie ich Lust **dazu** habe!

Please explain when I can and can't separate the preposition from "da".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Splitting *Präpositionaladverbien* like this is common in some spoken varieties in Germany, mostly as you go up north.  It is never considered acceptable in any of the written standard varieties, and neither in many other dialect groups (certainly not Bavarian including most Austrian dialects, and I think also not in Swiss German).

Where acceptable, this is also possible with most other *da*-forms, e.g.

> Da kann man Suppe mit machen (= damit kann man Suppe machen)

Comment: What you said is also true for all southern german dialects: Viennese, Tyrolean, Styrian, Carinthian, etc.. As fasr as i know it is only acceptable in central and northern parts of Germany (and the dialects spoken there, respectively).

Comment: Yes, all of those are Bavarian (in the linguistic sense).

Comment: I think, most well-known example is _Da nich' für!_.

Comment: Da kommt mir schon leicht das Grauen von :P